# How to set values to a Webelement from the steps test class?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, pageobjects

I'm trying to have a page object class with just the elements inside it.
but when using a instance from the steps (testclass) I can't use them.
the Xpaths are correct, if I try to call them inside my Steps it works.

If possible I just wanna call them and handle on Steps
like: loginScreen.loginUser.sendKeys("userX");

Here is my PageObject:

```
import com.test.core.BasePage;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;


public class LoginScreen extends BasePage {

    public String baseUrl = "https://10.125.103.235:6501/opt/security_check";

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@id='userId']")
    public WebElement loginUser;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@id='password']")
    public WebElement loginPassword;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@id='loginButton']")
    public WebElement loginEnter;

    
    public LoginScreen(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public void set_user(String user){
        loginUser.sendKeys(user);
    }

    public void set_password(String password){
        loginPassword.sendKeys(password);
    }

    public void clickOnEnter(){
        loginEnter.click();
    }

}
```

And here my Steps

```
import com.test.core.BaseTest;
import com.test.screens.LoginScreen;
import io.cucumber.java.en.And;
import io.cucumber.java.pt.Dado;

public class LoginSteps extends BaseTest{

    LoginScreen loginScreen = new LoginScreen(getDriver());

    @Dado("que o usuario acesse o PSRM")
    public void browserOpenPsrm() {
        loginScreen.driver.manage().window().maximize();
        loginScreen.driver.get(loginScreen.baseUrl);
    }

    @And("realiza o login com o USER: {string} e SENHA: {string}")
    public void loginSuccess(String user, String senha) {
        loginScreen.set_user(user);
        loginScreen.set_password(senha);
        loginScreen.clickOnEnter();

    }
}
```

error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:70)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:39)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.sendKeys(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.screens.LoginScreen.set_user(LoginScreen.java:32)
    at com.test.stepdefinitions.LoginSteps.loginSuccess(LoginSteps.java:23)
```

Comment: Post your BasPage.java file code

Comment: `PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);` is invoked with `null` driver. Variable `driver` is not initialized

Answer (score 1):

Issue Line: LoginScreen loginScreen = new LoginScreen(getDriver());

In your 'LoginSteps', you have initialised your non-static LoginScreen object on class level. Hence, after class loading, initialization of the class takes place which means initializing all **static members of the class*.**
Pleas, initialise your loginScreen object inside a Before method so that it gets initialised when class is loaded.

```
LoginScreen loginScreen;
        
@Before
public void beforeScenario(){
    loginScreen = new LoginScreen(getDriver());
    System.out.println("This will run before the Scenario");
}
```